# Constructing Regex to match anything in an array of `inclusions` string literals, excluding anything in `exclusions`

Tags: regex, parse-platform

I have two arrays of string literals: `inclusions` and `exclusions`. I'd like to create a Regex which will match a string if it contains any of the `inclusions`, but only if it matches **none** of the `exclusions`.

Given the sample case `inclusions=[learning,test]` and `exclusions=[machine]`:

- `learning` should match
- `this is a test, cool!` should match
- `machine learning` should **not** match
- `learning about machines` should **not** match
- `deep learning, machine learning` should **not** match

My basic approach is to try to build a query that does a greedy negative look-ahead on the exclusions, then matches on the inclusions... not sure if that's along the right lines or not, though.

FWIW, I want to do this in a single regex query because it's being used on a `Parse.Query` (parse.com), and I'd like to be able to paginate the results.

Comment: Does it *have* *have* *have* to be regex? Simple substring-in-string checks are really simple.

Comment: @ap yes. See the last paragraph of my question. Here's the documentation on `Parse.Query.matches()`, which accepts regex: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I now think the most correct answer is to wrap the `inclusions` with negative look-ahead and look-back on the `exclusions`, like so:

```
include, exclude = '|'.join(inclusions), '|'.join(exclusions)
regexp = r'''^(?!%s)(%s)(?<!%s)$''' % (exclude, include, exclude)
```

Original post resumes below:

```
^((?!machine).)*(learning|test)$
```

Okay well, let's torture regex a bit. Negative look-around guarantees that 'machine' won't be in our text, and then we can just have a bunch of pipe-joined inclusion literals.

More generally, `"^((?!%s).)*(%s)$" % ('|'.join(exclusions), '|'.join(inclusions))` - pick your language to format your lists in I guess.

Comment: Oh man, so close! This fails for `learning about machine learning`, providing a false-positive (since it contains `machine`, it should not match).

Comment: I think I fixed it by repeating the negative condition after the positive: `^((?!machine).)*(learning|test)((?!machine).)*$`

Comment: @ZaneClaes Oh yeah I think that yours works as well.

Comment: We could also have done a negative lookbehind at the end for 'exclusions', I guess, something like `^(joined|indcludes)(?<!joined|excludes)$` - but screw it if the current way works ;)

Comment: @ZaneClaes for the record, I've been thinking about this a little bit and the LEAST buggy, most correct way of doing this would be the following: `^(?!exclusions)(inclusions)(?<!exclusions)$` -- basically, wrap the inclusions with *explicit* negative look-ahead and look-back. I'm going to update the answer with this for any future googlers who come by the question.